# Idea behind choosing $f(x)$ as $f(x) = c^{s}x^{p-1} \frac{[\theta(x)]^{p}}{(p-1)!}$ in the proof that $\pi$ is transcendental

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra

I am going through the article at this [link](http://sixthform.info/maths/files/pitrans.pdf), where the author proves that $\pi$ is $\text{transcendental}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Although, I understand the proof, I have some doubts.

- At page $6$, the author defines a new function $f(x)$ as $$f(x) = c^{s}x^{p-1} \frac{[\theta(x)]^{p}}{(p-1)!}$$ Can anyone tell me what is the motivation behind defining $f(x)$ in this manner.

Comment: [Crossposted to MO](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/78170/idea-behind-choosing-small-fx-as-csxp-1-frac-thetaxpp-1).

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that you want to show that some real number $x$ is transcendental. There is a standard way for going at this. This is introducing a so called "auxiliary function". In that paper, I think the auxiliary function is $F(x)$. You prove that, under the assumption that  $x$ is algebraic, you show, for example, that $F(x)$ is positive and has a zero. (I didn't look what they actually do in the paper you quote.) The point is to derive a contradiction this way.  All the proofs in transcendence theory (that I know) are done this way.

Finding the (or should I say "an") auxiliary polynomial is more of a puzzle actually.

Comment: Regarding "all proofs in transcendence theory", I always thought that Liouville's constant was proved trancendental directly by showing that it cannot be root in any integer polynomial, because there comes a point in the constant where the nonzero decimals are too far from each other for bounded multiples of their powers (up to the degree of the polynomial) to cancel out.

Comment: Indeed, in the case of Liouville numbers the proof is very easy: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number

Comment: I didn't know. Thnx!